# Cómo almacenar varias instancias de un objeto en Java?

Tags: java, array, revisión-de-código, poo

Tengo un código hecho.. pero en él me salen 2 dudas.

1. ¿Está bien? Es mi primer programa orientado a objetos y no sé si está 100% correcto.
2. Me gustaría poder crear varias `Nurses`, no solo 1, pero no sé cómo se hace. Ahora mismo me guardaría solo 1 y yo necesito guardar varias sin saber cuántas.

A continuación, el código:

```
package principal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author MiguelAngel
 */
public class Nurse {

    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    /*
     TODO Constructor
     Paràmetres: String nif, String name, String lastname
     Accions:
     - actualitzar les propietats que ens han passat per paràmetre
     */
    public Nurse(String nif, String name, String lastname) {
        this.nif = nif;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getNif(){ return nif; }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public String getLastname(){ return lastname ; }

    public void setNif(String Nif){ this.nif = Nif;}
    public void setName(String Name){ this.name = Name;}
    public void setLastname(String Lastname){ this.lastname = Lastname ;}

    /*
     TODO Mètodes accessors    
     */
    public static Nurse addNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades per consola per crear un nou infermer (són les dades que demana el constructor)
         Retorneu: L'infermer creat
         */
    // carreguem    
        int contUser=0, cod=1; //variable llevar control usuarios ingresados


        Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
        String nif = Nurse1.getNif();
        String name = Nurse1.getName();
        String lastname = Nurse1.getLastname();

// creem a sobre 

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
        nif = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setNif(nif);

        System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
        name = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setName(name);

        System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
        lastname = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setLastname(lastname);

        return Nurse1;
    }

    public void updateNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades de l'infermer per consola i modifiqueu la propietat corresponent
         Nota: penseu que estem modificant l'objecte actual ...
         Retorneu: no hi ha retorn
         */
        Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
        System.out.println("Modifiquem Nurse ");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
        String code = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setNif(code);

        System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
        String nom = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setName(nom);

        System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
        String cognom = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setLastname(cognom);

    }

    public void showNurse() {
        System.out.println("\nLes dades de l'infermer amb nif " + this.getNif() + " són:");
        System.out.println("\nNom:" + this.getName());
        System.out.println("\nCognom:" + this.getLastname());
    }

}
```

Tanto las clases como los java doc los tengo obligados.. es decir no se puede modificar ninguna clase..

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN!!**

Ante las dudas, os comento.

Estoy obligada a tener esta parte del código:

```
public class Nurse {

    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    /*
     TODO Constructor
     Paràmetres: String nif, String name, String lastname
     Accions:
     - actualitzar les propietats que ens han passat per paràmetre
     */


    /*
     TODO Mètodes accessors    
     */
    public static Nurse addNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades per consola per crear un nou infermer (són les dades que demana el constructor)
         Retorneu: L'infermer creat
         */


return ............
    }

    public void updateNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades de l'infermer per consola i modifiqueu la propietat corresponent
         Nota: penseu que estem modificant l'objecte actual ...
         Retorneu: no hi ha retorn
         */


    }

    public void showNurse() {
        System.out.println("\nLes dades de l'infermer amb nif " + this.getNif() + " són:");
        System.out.println("\nNom:" + this.getName());
        System.out.println("\nCognom:" + this.getLastname());
    }

}
```

¿Qué tengo que hacer? 
La función `AddNurse()`
Crear X enfermeros (`nombre`, `apellido` y `Nif`) por teclado.

La función `updateNurse()`
Modificar los enfermeros.

No sé si mi código es 100% correcto, cualquier ayuda me irá genial!

gracias!

---

**FINAL**

El problema que tenía es que no podía crear una lista ya que no ha salido en temario. El código final ha quedado así:

```
package principal;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class Nurse {

    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    /*
     TODO Constructor
     Paràmetres: String nif, String name, String lastname
     Accions:
     - actualitzar les propietats que ens han passat per paràmetre
     */
    public Nurse(String nif, String name, String lastname) {
        this.nif = nif;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getNif(){ return nif; }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public String getLastname(){ return lastname ; }

    public void setNif(String Nif){ this.nif = Nif;}
    public void setName(String Name){ this.name = Name;}
    public void setLastname(String Lastname){ this.lastname = Lastname ;}

    /*
     TODO Mètodes accessors    
     */
    public static Nurse addNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades per consola per crear un nou infermer (són les dades que demana el constructor)
         Retorneu: L'infermer creat
         */
// carreguem    

    Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
    String nif = Nurse1.getNif();
    String name = Nurse1.getName();
    String lastname = Nurse1.getLastname();

// creem a sobre 

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
    System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
    nif = lector.next();
    Nurse1.setNif(nif);

    System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
    name = lector.next();
    Nurse1.setName(name);

    System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
    lastname = lector.next();
    Nurse1.setLastname(lastname);

    return Nurse1;
    }

    public void updateNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades de l'infermer per consola i modifiqueu la propietat corresponent
         Nota: penseu que estem modificant l'objecte actual ...
         Retorneu: no hi ha retorn
         */

        Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
        System.out.println("Modifiquem Nurse ");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
          System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
        String code = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setNif(code);

        System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
        String nom = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setName(nom);

        System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
        String cognom = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setLastname(cognom);

    }

    public void showNurse() {
        System.out.println("\nLes dades de l'infermer amb nif " + this.getNif() + " són:");
        System.out.println("\nNom:" + this.getName());
        System.out.println("\nCognom:" + this.getLastname());
    }

}
```

Luego, he creado en la clase principal:

```
static private Nurse[] nurses = new Nurse[100]; 
static private int contador = 0;
```

Y en la llamada a la función:

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("has escollit Alta"); 
    Nurse n = Nurse.addNurse(); 
    nurses[contador] = n; 
    contador ++; 
    break;
```

Comment: Es una tarea de escuela? =)

Comment: si... :(  Estoy intentando hacerlo lo mejor posible.. :( pero voy un poco perdida al ser a distancia..

Comment: Para crear List revisa la respuesta de Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2. Me gustaría poder crear varias Nurses no solo 1.. pero no sé como se hace.. es decir ahora mismo me guardaría solo 1.. Y yo necesito guardar varias sin saber cuantas..

como dices que *sin saber cuantas* tienes que crear una `List`a para almacenar cada instancia que crees:

```
List<Nurse> nurses = new ArrayList<Nurse>();
```

Cuando crees una nueva enfermera:

```
Nurse nurseA = new Nurse("333444555", "Nom", "Cognom");
```

La añades asi:

```
nurses.add(nurseA);
```

Tambien puedes usar el metodo estatico `addNurse()` que has creado:

```
Nurse nurseB = Nurse.addNurse();
nurses.add(nurseB);
```

O lo que es lo mismo:

```
nurses.add(Nurse.addNurse());
```

---

Algunos añadidos observando tu codigo:

- Uso `ArrayList` porque aunque no lo uses lo tienes importado
- Las java conventions dicen que los nombres de las variables van en minuscula, por lo tanto `Nurse nurseA`
- Tienes una variable para llevar el control de usuarios ingresados:

  1. Updateala a cada `Nurse` que añadas
  2. Borrala y usa `nurses.size()` para no tener problemas de descontrol

---

Mira [esta demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/5sOraH) con el metodo main y las listas de ejemplo, puedes copiartelo a tu IDE para ejecutarlo en local descomentando las lineas para crear enfermeros por consola:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // creem la llista per afegir infermers
    List<Nurse> nurses = new ArrayList<Nurse>();
    // creem un infermer
    Nurse nurseA = new Nurse("333444555", "Joan", "Casademunt");
    // afegim un infermer
    nurses.add(nurseA);
    // creem un infermer
    nurseA = new Nurse("654987", "Maria", "Serra");
    // afegim un infermer
    nurses.add(nurseA);
    // creem unaltra infermer (al ideone no es pot fer)
    //Nurse nurseB = Nurse.addNurse();
    // l'afegim
    //nurses.add(nurseB);
    // tambe es pot fer aixi
    // nurses.add(Nurse.addNurse());

    // recorrem tots els infermers i els ensenyem
    for (Nurse n : nurses) {
        n.showNurse();
    }

    // si tens mes dubtes, pregunta! ;) 
}
```

---

PD: suerte y pregunta lo que necessites ;)

Comment: el problema es que no hemos usado los LIST y creo que tengo que hacerlo de otra forma.

Igualmente me lo explicas pero no acabo de entender 100% como tengo que hacerlo.. :(

Es decir tengo que crear las enfermeras por teclado.. no entiendo la parte que ya escribes la info de la enfermera.. T_T

Comment: no lo he puesto, pero... sabes que tienes que crear una clase Main que sea el programa que se ejecuta y crear alli el array o la list para almacenar las Nurses?

Comment: No sé si puedes ponerme un ejemplo de ejercicio para verlo más claro.. perdón T_T

Comment: Hola jordi!

El problema es que el programa es bastante más extenso.. esto es una de las pestañas.. 

Por eso estoy un poco perdida... :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36426/discussion-between-jordi-castilla-and-montse-mkd).

Comment: @JordiCastilla El único idioma admitido en este sitio es el español. Por favor, escribe en ese idioma aunque te estés dirigiendo a una persona que sabes que conoce otro que tú también dominas. Piensa que el contenido publicado aquí es leído por (y puede ser útil para) toda la comunidad.

Comment: @Konamiman ni en el chat? entiendo lo de los comentarios aqui (no en el codigo, cada uno escribe los comentarios y los nombres de los metodos como quiere en todo stack exchage). Pero creo que antes que borrarlos, es mejor pedir que los traduzca, sino dejas cojo el foro...  Creo que mejor comentarios en catalán (o cualquier otro idioma) que no borrados, que siempre se puede usar google. **PD: si vamos asi, no dejemos usar dialectos y hablemos en castellano normativo, porque yo de muchas expresiones no me entero por ser locales**

Comment: a lo de ir asi, me refiero a lo de borrar los comentarios. Lo del idioma lo puedo entender.

Comment: @JordiCastilla En el chat no hay problema (pero mejor si es en una sala privada, no en el chat principal). Por otro lado, he borrado los comentarios de aquí porque he visto que ya se había creado la sala de chat; si contenían información importante, esta debería incluirse en la pregunta o en la respuesta.

Comment: @Konamiman *si contenían información importante, esta debería incluirse en la pregunta o en la respuesta* estoy de acuerdo con eso, pero **ya no lo puedo hacer porque los has eliminado**. De ahí mi queja, prefiero comentarios en ingles que borrados, ahi si que proximos users se pueden perder, ademas, creo que no es la actitud adecuada por parte de un moderador el ir borrando información unilateralmente (lo digo porque si no los entiendes, no sabes que dicen y, por lo tanto, es un error eliminarlos, creo que lo correcto es que me pidas que actualice la respuesta o que los traduzca).

Answer (score 3):

Podrías crear un ArrayList del tipo Nurse

```
ArrayList <Nurse> NurseArrayList= new ArrayList <Nurse> ();

NurseArrayList.add(new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname"))
NurseArrayList.add(new Nurse("Nif2", "Name2", "Lastname2"))
NurseArrayList.add(new Nurse("Nif3", "Name3", "Lastname3"))
```

y así sucesivamente

Mas Info:

La sintaxis para crear el ArrayList de Objetos es la siguiente:

```
ArrayList <ClaseDelObjeto> NombreArrayList= new ArrayList <ClaseDelObjeto> ();
```

`ClaseDelObjeto` => La clase que vamos a emplear para el manejo de los datos del objeto.
`NombreArrayList` => El nombre del ArrayList que vamos a manipular.

Los anteriores son datos que se reemplazan con los nombres que deseemos y debamos usar. Para usar esta sintaxis debemos de importar las librerias necesarias para usar el ArrayList:

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

MÉTODOS ÚTILES PARA UN ARRAYLIST EN JAVA

Para realizar las operaciones comunes tales como ingresar, eliminar, buscar, modificar datos en un ArrayList encontraremos algunos métodos útiles para tal objetivo:

- `add(X)` -> Añade un valor u objeto al final del ArrayList.
- `size()` -> Retorna el tamaño del ArrayList.
- `contains(X)` -> Retorna true si existe el elemento X en el ArrayList.
- `set(i, X)` -> Modifica el elemento que esta en la posición i, por el nuevo elemento X.
- `remove(X)` -> Elimina el elemento X o en su defecto el elemento en la posición X.
- `get(i)` -> Obtiene el elemento en la posición i del Array List.

Comment: El problema es que nunca he creado una List y estoy algo perdida.. sé que me pide el ejercicio crear varios.. pero no se si por lista ya que en el temario no lo hemos tocado.. T_T

Comment: Es muy Útil y practico. Te recomiendo que leas un poco como hacer un ForEach a un ArrayList, y asi podes ver como podes recuperar fácilmente los datos de un ArrayList

Comment: Gracias!!! xD Acabaré el ejercicio haber si puedo y procedo a leer!! xD

Answer (score 3):

He tenido que borrar parte de la respuesta porque [Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5030/java-orientado-a-objetos#5036) fue mas rapido, parece que usted esta usando Nurse de una manera como un nodo/arbol que crea añade nodos, de una forma mucho mas simple y que no se igual pero, para que se entienda el ejemplo, aplicando su respuesta de Ariel usted puede hacer algo asi:

Tomese como pseudo code:

Main

```
ArrayList <Nurse> nurseArrayList= new ArrayList <Nurse> ();

//esto añade tantas como dure el for
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){ 
    nurseArrayList.add(Nurse.addNurse());
}
```

Usted dice que no sabe cuantas, pero no se, si se refiere a que no sabe cuantas va a almacenar a lo largo de su programa, o a que se refiere, si es a que el usuario por CLI (por consola) usted le pide un numero y estas son las que añadira, si es asi solo tiene que cambiar el 10 por el valor que le pase el usuario.

---

Update:

> ................................problema es que yo tengo la clase
>   principal ( que hago que el usuario escoja si quiere dar de alta a
>   enfermeras ) switch (opcio) { case 0: break; case 1:
>   System.out.println("has escollit Alta"); Nurse.addNurse(); break; Y
>   esto lo lleva al AddNurse() Entonces no sé donde poner esta parte:

```
switch (opcio) { 
   case 0: 
   break; 
   case 1:
     System.out.println("has escollit Alta"); 
     puedeLlamarAUnMetodo(); //Llama al metodo "asumiendo que este este disponible desde aqui"
  break;
```

---

```
..//
ArrayList <Nurse> nurseArrayList= new ArrayList <Nurse> ();
..//
void puedeLlamarAUnMetodo(){

   nurseArrayList.add(Nurse.addNurse());  
}
```

---

```
public static Nurse addNurse() {
        /*
         TODO 
         Paràmetres: sense
         Accions:
         - demanar les dades per consola per crear un nou infermer (són les dades que demana el constructor)
         Retorneu: L'infermer creat
         */
    // carreguem    
        int contUser=0, cod=1; //variable llevar control usuarios ingresados


        Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
        String nif = Nurse1.getNif();
        String name = Nurse1.getName();
        String lastname = Nurse1.getLastname();

// creem a sobre 

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
        nif = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setNif(nif);

        System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
        name = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setName(name);

        System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
        lastname = lector.next();
        Nurse1.setLastname(lastname);

        return Nurse1;
    }
```

> 

segun leo tienes que usar `showNurse` una manera sencilla seria pasarle el Array:

```
public void showNurse(ArrayList <Nurse> nurseArrayList) {

        //para mostrar todas
        for(int a = 0; a < nurseArrayList.size(); a++){

        System.out.println("\nLes dades de l'infermer amb nif " + nurseArrayList.get(a).getNif() + " són:");
        System.out.println("\nNom:" + nurseArrayList.get(a).getName());
        System.out.println("\nCognom:" + nurseArrayList.get(a).getLastname());

        }
    }
```

> 

Para el otro `updateNurse`, le pasas el Array y el string que corresponda con el nif:

```
public void updateNurse(ArrayList <Nurse> nurseArrayList, string actualizarPorNif) {

//en este caso igual te podria ser util usar algun map
for(int a = 0; a < nurseArrayList.size(); a++){
    if(nurseArrayList.get(a).getNif().equals(actualizarPorNif){

       System.out.println("Modifiquem Nurse ");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.println("Nif nurse??");
        String code = lector.next();
        nurseArrayList.get(a).setNif(code);

        System.out.println("Nom Nurse??");
        String nom = lector.next();
        nurseArrayList.get(a).setName(nom);

        System.out.println("Cognom Nurse???");
        String cognom = lector.next();
        nurseArrayList.get(a).setLastname(cognom); 
    }
}
}
```

---

Notas: Tomese todo esto como pseudo code no a sido testeado ni se a creado en ningun ide (syntax), tambien es muy posible que esta no sea la forma mas eficiente ni correcta pero creo que puede usarlo como base.

Comment: me encanta tu código pero es el problema es que yo tengo la clase principal ( que hagoque el usuario escoja si quiere dar de alta a enfermeras ) 

switch (opcio) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("has escollit Alta");
                    Nurse.addNurse();
                    break;

Y esto lo lleva al AddNurse()

Entonces no sé donde poner esta parte:

Comment: ArrayList <Nurse> NurseArrayList= new ArrayList <Nurse> ();

for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){ 
    NurseArrayList.add(Nurse.addNurse());
}

Comment: La clase general es: http://ideone.com/JKZceg

el menu : http://ideone.com/BONN4x

La clase enfermera es la que tenemos en esta página!

Comment: el tema es que no solo llamo a eso ... Te pongo el enlace para que eches un ojo!

http://ideone.com/WPur8p

Answer (score 2):

**1)**
Es correcto tu código a grandes rasgos (sería bueno aplicarle un formato), pero depende de que requerimientos debe tener, debe tener tres propiedades?, un método para mostrar los datos?, un método para actualizar?. Que requiere tu código? en base a eso se puede determinar si esta bien y cumple con los objetivos.

**2)**
 Para crear varias "Nurse", simplemente debes crear una nueva instancia lo cual realizas en tu programa mediante: `new Nurse()`.

```
Nurse Nurse1 = new Nurse("Nif", "Name", "Lastname");
```

por ejemplo vamos a agregar  3 instancias de "Nurse":
Primeramente creas una lista de objetos tipo Nurse:

```
List<Nurse> nurses = new ArrayList<Nurse>();
```

Creas instancias de Nurse:

```
Nurse nurseA = new Nurse("123", "Maria", "abc");
Nurse nurseB = new Nurse("456", "Montse", "def");
Nurse nurseC = new Nurse("789", "Alba", "ghi");
```

y las agregas a la lista mediante el método [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) así:

```
nurses.add(nurseA);
nurses.add(nurseB);
nurses.add(nurseC);
```

Comment: El problema es que no sé cuantas enfermeras voy a crear.. ese es el problema..

Yo no te he puesto el negativo.. xD

Actualizo mi mensaje para ser más clara!

Comment: no hace falta que pongas excusas, Me vale simplemente con que la hayas editado, aunque dar las gracias por los consejos no estaria de más. ;)  No se tardan 20m y se comenta alegremente *ya me dieron un -1 =P haha, ¿porque razón?* si la estas editando.... digo yo...

Comment: Nueva regla, no se puede editar una respuesta después de agregarse, los consejos se toman de la gente sabia y humilde.

Answer (score 2):

Sobre si el programa está bien, si compila *técnicamente* está bien. Si se ejecuta como lo espera, está aún mejor. Si la pregunta hace referencia a si está bien de acuerdo a la metodología de análisis, diseño y programación orientado a objetos, es relativo. Ni en la misma literatura hay consenso sobre cuáles características logran ajustarse a estos requisitos. Aún así, trataré de mencionar los clásicos rasgos:

1. Encapsulamiento: la clase Nurse tiene tres atributos (nif, name, lastName) que son privados. Y ha implementado los tres getters y setters correspondientes para ellos, por lo que cumple este atributo. Aún así, valores como `null`, `""`, `" "` pueden ser seteadas a estos atributos. No sería nada bueno tener una enfermera con nombre Diana y apellido `null` por ejemplo. Encapsulamiento trata, primero, de cómo ocultamos la representación de los datos y segundo, de cómo validamos que estos datos estén correctos. La propiedad `nif` no es clara, supongo yo que representa un número de identificación: una cualidad del encapsulamiento es que es decisión suya que esta propiedad sea de tipo entera o String, una tiene ventajas sobre las otras, dependiendo del uso que le dé a esta información. Supongo yo que no hay ninguna restricción para estos valores por lo que en últimas cumple el propósito.
2. La clase cuenta con un constructor que recibe como parámetro las tres propiedades mencionadas anteriormente. Eso es correcto en tiempo de compilación. En tiempo de ejecución puede o no ser correcto dependiendo de cuáles datos de la clase `Nurse` sean estrictamente necesarios para interactuar. En este momento es *obligatorio* que todo objeto de tipo `Nurse` sea creado con estos campos. Es una regla estricta, pero así lo ha decidido usted, no hay ningún error en esto.
3. La clase `Nurse` cuenta con un método para crear un objeto de su tipo, aprovechando los métodos `static` disponibles en Java. Para algunos autores estos métodos rompen el principio orientado a objetos (¿es reponsabilidad de la clase `Nurse` crear objetos de su tipo? (diferentes al constructor, obviamente)). Otros autores por el contrario manifiestan que es correcto (patrón de diseño Builder o Factory). Mi opinión personal es que estos deberían diseñarse con el único objetivo de crear objetos, delegando el ingreso de datos a clases auxiliares. Su clase `addNurse` no sólamente se está encargando de crear el objeto, sino de interactuar con métodos de clase que sirven para pedir datos al usuario (`Scanner`).
4. De acuerdo la responsabilidad de pedir los datos al usuario para crear un objeto de tipo `Nurse` debe ser otorgada a una clase auxiliar (normalmente sería la que usa para invocar los métodos de esta clase o construir objetos de este tipo)
5. El método `addNurse` podría implementarse así:

   ```
    public static Nurse createNurse(String nif, String name, String lastName) {
       return new Nurse(nif,name,lastName);
    }
   ```

   aparte de cambiar el nombre (pues en realidad este método sólo crea objetos de este tipo) se auxilia en el constructor para retornar un objeto con los datos enviados. Es responsabilidad de la clase que invoca este método pedir los datos (`nif`, `name`, `lastName`) para construir el objeto e incluso, validar si son correctos, ya que la clase `Nurse` no lo hace.
6. Pienso que el método `update` es redundante. Para actualizar un objeto hacemos uso de sus métodos seters públicos, por lo que delegamos la responsabilidad de actualizar los valores de cada objeto a la clase que los invoca.
7. El método `showNurse` es correcto. Sin embargo (más práctica de Java que orientado a objetos) es muy bueno implementar un método llamado `toString()` que realiza exactamente lo mismo que este método: la diferencia radica en que al imprimir un objeto de tipo `Nurse` se invoca automáticamente el método `toString()` con el formato que haya diseñado, por ejemplo:

   ```
       @Override 
       public String toString() {
           return "\nLes dades de l'infermer amb nif " + this.getNif() + " són:" + "\nNom:" + this.getName() + "\nCognom:" + this.getLastname();
       }
   ```
8. Aunque ya le han respondido, puede crear varios objetos de tipo `Nurse` de varias formas. Si conoce de antemano cuántos objetos necesita, use un arreglo:

   ```
   //Crea un arreglo de 10 objetos de tipo `Nurse`
   Nurse[] nurses = new Nurse[10]
   ```

   si no conoce cuántos objetos son y necesita ir creando conforme el programa se ejecuta, cree un Array:

   ```
   ArrayList<Nurse> nurses = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   e inserta en este arreglo cada objeto que quiera ir creando:

   ```
   nurses.add(new Nurse("1","Diana","Salinas"));
   nurses.add(new Nurse("2","Esperanza","Acosta"));
   ```

Comment: el problema por ejemplo con el show es que es directamente por el profesor y no puedo modificarlo!

Y el problema es que tengo que añadir las enfermeras por teclado cuando me pones esto:-

Comment: nurses.add(new Nurse("1","Diana","Salinas"));
nurses.add(new Nurse("2","Esperanza","Acosta"));

No lo estás añadiendo manualmentE?